# Factor levels by group

Tags: r, syntax, data.table, refactoring, levels

I have a data.table that looks as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
    "Sex   Height   
     M   180   
     F   179
     F   162   
     M   181  
     M   165   
     M   178   
     F   172   
     F   160",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I would like to split the height into groups. However, I want separate groups for men and women. The following code gives me three factor level, where I would like six.

```
dt[,height_f := cut(Height, breaks = c(0, 165, 180, 300), right = FALSE), by="Sex"]

> table(dt$height_f)

  [0,165) [165,180) [180,300) 
        2         4         2
```

I have the feeling that it should be something very simple, but I cannot figure out how to write it.

Desired output:

```
> table(dt$height_f)

  M:[0,165) M:[165,180) M:[180,300) F:[0,165) F:[165,180) F:[180,300) 
        0         3          1            2         2         0
```

Comment: Are you sure about the desired output? I only get 2 observations in "M:[165,180)".

Comment: @sindry_baldur No, I did it by hand, might have made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
dt[, height_cat := cut(Height, breaks = c(0, 165, 180, 300), right = FALSE)]
dt[, height_f := 
       factor(
         paste(Sex, height_cat, sep = ":"), 
         levels = dt[, CJ(Sex, height_cat, unique = TRUE)][, paste(Sex, height_cat, sep = ":")]
       )]

table(dt$height_f)
# F:[0,165) F:[165,180) F:[180,300)   M:[0,165) M:[165,180) M:[180,300) 
#         2           2           0           0           2           2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be appropriate. We don't end up using `table` to show the output, although I think the tibble output is probably more useful anyway:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
    mutate(Height = cut(Height, breaks = c(0, 166, 181, 301))) %>%
    group_by(Sex, Height, .drop = FALSE) %>%
    summarise(n = n())

## A tibble: 6 x 3
## Groups:   Sex [2]
#  Sex   Height        n
#  <chr> <fct>     <int>
#1 F     (0,166]       2
#2 F     (166,181]     2
#3 F     (181,301]     0
#4 M     (0,166]       1
#5 M     (166,181]     3
#6 M     (181,301]     0
```

Note that the `breaks` argument can be read as "up until this number", so to get your desired output we need to add 1 to each integer (that is, `breaks = c(0, 166, 181, 301`). We also need to specify `.drop = FALSE` if we want the empty groups to show up like in your desired output (this defaults to `TRUE`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, `levels(dt$Height)` still gives me only three levels.. The point was to create a new factor variable with three levels per gender (so six).